# How to extract the div_class table from betting website

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I was searching continuously and I ran out of luck. I'm trying to just get the text of the games being played on https://www.sportsinteraction.com/football/nfl-betting-lines/. So at the end I want something to spit out like the below (doesn't have to be clean).

Carolina Panthers
Houston Texans 
POINTSPREAD
+4.0
1.90
-4.0
1.92

MONEYLINE
2.69
1.49

OVER/UNDER
O
+47.0
1.91
U
+47.0
1.91

Code below which is obviously wrong:

```
    Sub Pulldata2()

 Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
 Dim appIE As Object
 Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim strSheet As String

    strSheet = Sheet2.Range("P2")
    i = 1

    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = False
    ieObj.navigate Sheet2.Range("P2").Value


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Sheet13.Activate

    For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("game")(0)
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A1").Value

    End With
    i = i + 1
    On Error Resume Next
Next htmlEle



End Sub
```

Comment: There are plenty of apis out there to give you this data.  Scraping a site week after week is a moving target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why?**

This is an interesting scrape for practice so worth the time to attempt. It is interesting because there isn't an immediately obvious way to 'block' out each event with the associated meta data e.g. date, time, match title; and the betting content switches between horizontal and vertical groupings making your selector strategy for identifying nodes particularly important.

---

**Strategy:**

The strategy I decided to employ was the following: Use css class selectors to grab a long list of nodes containing all the info required. `date, time and title` would be nodes whose info I would need to repeat across the two lines for each team within each `gameBettingContent` block.

Note: the content is static so [XHR](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) can be used to avoid the overhead of opening a browser and rendering unnecessary content. This method is a lot quicker.

---

**Anatomy of a logical block:**

[image]

Note that each parent node with class `gameBettingContent` contains 3 child nodes with class `betTypeContent`. These children correspond with `PointSpread, MoneyLine and Over/Under`. These will need to occupy their own columns in the output including separating out `price` from `handicap`. For each logical block, as shown above, there will be two rows where some info is repeated in the first few columns of output.

---

**The nodeList:**

So, initially we have a `nodeList` of all elements of interest matched on `className`. Within some of those nodes are children that we then need to access; to avoid complicated accessor syntax, when we get to nodes whose children (or deeper nodes) we need to access, we load the html of that node into a 'surrogate', i.e. new, `HTMLDocument` variable, so we can leverage `querySelectorAll` method of `HTMLDocument` again. This gives us easy to read syntax and the cost is minimal.

[image]

We loop the `nodeList`, shown on left above, and test the `className` of each current node and use a `Select Case` statement to then determine what to do. If the current className is `date, time or title` we store that node's `.innerText` for later use (remember we need to repeat this value across runner 1 and runner 2). If the `className` is `gameBettingContent` we load that node's `outerHTML` into a surrogate `HTMLDocument` i.e. `html2`. We can then collect the `runners` and start populating our output array `resultsTable`. We add +2 to the `r` variable (row counter), initially, so we are ready for the next logical block (i.e. match), and then populate the 2 positions for the current match using `r-2` and `r-1`.

---

**Using surrogate HTMLDocument variables to leverage `querySelectorAll` on nodes deeper in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction):**

As we are using `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` with `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` we do not have access to [nth-of-type pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) css selector syntax (which you do with `ie.document` when using `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`) to differentiate between the 3 divs (columns) for bet types within `gameBettingContent`; whilst we could chain class selectors and [adjacent sibling combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to move from left to right across the divs (columns) e.g.

*PointSpread:*

```
.gameBettingContent #runnerNames + .betTypeContent
```

*MoneyLine:*

```
.gameBettingContent #runnerNames + .betTypeContent + .betTypeContent
```

*Over/Under:*

```
.gameBettingContent #runnerNames + .betTypeContent + .betTypeContent + .betTypeContent
```

I find it cleaner to simply gather those divs into a nodeList

```
Set contentDivs = html2.querySelectorAll(".betTypeContent")
```

Then load each div's (column's) `outerHTML` into a new `HTMLDocument` surrogate `html3` and leverage querySelectorAll again to gather the two rows info by index from each column.

For example, `PointsSpread` will be the first node in `contentDivs` which we read across into `html3`:

```
html3.body.innerHTML = contentDivs.item(0).outerHTML
```

[image]

We then select handicap and price

```
Set pointSpreadHandicaps = html3.querySelectorAll(".handicap")
Set pointSpreadPrices = html3.querySelectorAll(".price")
```

And can use index to get runner 1 versus runner 2 values:

```
resultsTable(r - 2, 5) = pointSpreadHandicaps.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 5) = pointSpreadHandicaps.item(1).innerText
```

That's pretty much the bulk of the logic. The output array is dimensioned based on number of rows being equal to:

```
html.querySelectorAll("#runnerNames li").Length
```

i.e. how many runners there are. The number of columns is equal to the number of items we specified in the `headers` array (we add 1 to the `Ubound` as the array is 0-based). The array is then written out in one go to sheet as are headers.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetNFLMatchInfo()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, html2 As HTMLDocument

    Set html = New HTMLDocument: Set html2 = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.sportsinteraction.com/football/nfl-betting-lines/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim allNodes As Object, i As Long, resultsTable(), r As Long, headers()
    Dim dateValue As String, timeValue As String, title As String, html3 As HTMLDocument
    headers = Array("Date", "Time", "Title", "Team", "Pointspread handicap", "Pointspread price", "Moneyline price", "O/U Name", "O/U Handicap", "O/U Price")

    Set allNodes = html.querySelectorAll(".date, .time, .title, .gameBettingContent") 'nodeList of all items of interest. gameBettingContent is a block _
                                                                that will be further subdivided by reading its html into a 'surrogate' HTMLDocument
    ReDim resultsTable(1 To html.querySelectorAll("#runnerNames li").Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    r = 1: Set html3 = New HTMLDocument

    For i = 0 To allNodes.Length - 1
        With allNodes.item(i)
            Select Case .className
            Case "date"
                dateValue = .innerText
            Case "time"
                timeValue = .innerText
            Case "title"
                title = Trim$(.innerText)
            Case "gameBettingContent"
                Dim runners  As Object, contentDivs As Object, pointSpreadHandicaps As Object
                Dim pointSpreadPrices As Object, moneyLinePrices As Object, runners As Object
                Dim OuHandicaps As Object, OuPrices As Object

                r = r + 2                        'then fill line one at r-2, and line 2 at r-1
                html2.body.innerHTML = .outerHTML

                Set runners = html2.querySelectorAll("#runnerNames li")

                resultsTable(r - 2, 1) = dateValue: resultsTable(r - 1, 1) = dateValue
                resultsTable(r - 2, 2) = timeValue: resultsTable(r - 1, 2) = timeValue
                resultsTable(r - 2, 3) = title: resultsTable(r - 1, 3) = title
                resultsTable(r - 2, 4) = runners.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 4) = runners.item(1).innerText

                Set contentDivs = html2.querySelectorAll(".betTypeContent")
                html3.body.innerHTML = contentDivs.item(0).outerHTML

                'populate resultsTable for two rows relating to current gameBettingContent
                Set pointSpreadHandicaps = html3.querySelectorAll(".handicap")
                Set pointSpreadPrices = html3.querySelectorAll(".price")

                resultsTable(r - 2, 5) = pointSpreadHandicaps.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 5) = pointSpreadHandicaps.item(1).innerText
                resultsTable(r - 2, 6) = pointSpreadPrices.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 6) = pointSpreadPrices.item(1).innerText

                html3.body.innerHTML = contentDivs.item(1).outerHTML 'Set html3 content to next content div to right

                Set moneyLinePrices = html3.querySelectorAll(".price")
                resultsTable(r - 2, 7) = moneyLinePrices.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 7) = moneyLinePrices.item(1).innerText

                html3.body.innerHTML = contentDivs.item(2).outerHTML

                Set runners = html3.querySelectorAll(".name")
                Set OuHandicaps = html3.querySelectorAll(".handicap")
                Set OuPrices = html3.querySelectorAll(".price")

                resultsTable(r - 2, 8) = runners.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 8) = runners.item(1).innerText
                resultsTable(r - 2, 9) = OuHandicaps.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 9) = .item(1).innerText
                resultsTable(r - 2, 10) = OuPrices.item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 10) = OuPrices.item(1).innerText
            End Select
        End With
    Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(resultsTable, 1), UBound(resultsTable, 2)) = resultsTable
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Example selection from results:**

[image]

---

**Additional reading:**

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
2. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectoraLL)
3. [HTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument)

Comment: QHarr - you been killing it! You answered my other questions too before. This works great! One last thing - I tried changing the URL to https://www.sportsinteraction.com/basketball/nba-betting-lines/ and I got an error at
```resultsTable(r - 2, 8) = runners.Item(0).innerText: resultsTable(r - 1, 8) = runners.Item(1).innerText ```
any idea how to fix? btw your coding is insane, i barely could follow, will need to digest later on